# Wordpress not pulling CSS (I think...)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

Out of nothing a wordpress based website I work on has decided to stop pulling the CSS (at least I think that's what's happening)...

Here's a pic of the wordpress admin dashboard:

[image: site]

Unsure what has caused it... can anyone shine any light on the problem?

I've blocked the URL because the site doesn't belong to me and I'm not sure my boss would be happy with me posting a picture of it online! I've been asked to fix it, I didn't write the site and haven't much WordPress experience.

It was working fine until this morning, and nothing has changed.

EDIT - Further information on the problem:

I debugged this in Firefox Firebug and on the

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

It should be mentioned that it's a windows server running IIS7

Comment: You could verify this via the network tab of firebug. It shows if a file was loaded, is missing etc.

Comment: at-lest you have to give us that link/site address, how can someone on this earth can find an issue in code just from an image?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think my boss would be happy with me posting it, i'm only an intern too.

Comment: See my edit on the question. Think it's something to do with the server config but nothing has been changed (at least by me, and i doubt anyone would change this on a friday night/saturday morning in London)

Comment: To quote the last part of the same error message I get: `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.` - Checked it?

Comment: Can you get to the server in any other way? FTP, RDP, VPN, anything that allows you to see if the .css file is actually there and can be opened?

Comment: It's an IIS server? Turn it off and on again. (Seriously, restart IIS and see if the problem goes away.) And yes, obvious first step is to check your error logs.

Comment: Yeah I can get on it using RDP, and can open the css there. I'll check the error logs and restart the server now.

Answer (score 1):

This had happened to me as well. It usually goes away with a few browser refreshes. The dashboard functioned fine while it looked like this too.

Is the CSS loading for the front-end of the site?

Check your plugins if this problem persists. 
You may have to turn them off one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Adam, there are a few questions I have:

- Have you tried this in a new browser session (different browser even
  better)?
- Does the front-end of the website look fine with the correct CSS
  being loaded?
- When you view source or use the web inspector under the 'resources'
  tab, can you see the CSS file reference 'load-styles.php'. If you do the contents look like CSS rules?[image]

Comment: Hi, see my edit on the question. To answer your questions - 1. Yes and it's the same. 2. Nope, it's the whole site. 3. No i'm getting "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". Thanks for your help.

Comment: That means the wordpress engine is not parsing the script correctly, try disabling all plugins and see if it works and then enable them one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: Someone else managed to fix it, it was a 'duplicate mime type' or something

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether css is showing in view source or not, have you enabled any plugin or update any theme etc. because some time it may give errors. Please try to clear cache.

Try to refresh your browser by pressing Ctrl+F5 in windows and Ctrl+5 in mac. it might be browser cache issue.